# node-sass - I have my devDependency in my package.json but when I try to import it node-sass cannot find it and do not compile

Tags: css, sass, node-modules, node-sass

I'm building a style guide based on a Sass / CSS library I had built earlier. I installed the library in my `package.json` as a devDependency using `npm` (on `npm` I have a private package for my library). My problem is that when I try to compile Sass using `node-sass`, it returns following error:

> "Couldn't find the stylesheet to import"

The file I want to import is called `tsw.scss`. In any other project in which I have been using `node-sass`, I never had problems compiling (or at least I always managed to find them and solve them alone). So, I really can not understand, where I'm wrong this time. Could any of you help me understand what my mistake is and fix it?
Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me.

This is the code I used in my "styles.scss" file (of my style guide) in which I want, in fact, to import the library I previously created (the import that gives me the error is the import of the first line).

```css
@import "~@alllearnit/tsw/tsw";
@import "tsw-guide-styles";
```

If needed, I could share any part of my code that you may need to better understand my project and therefore to help you to solve the problem.
Thanks again for all the help you will give me

Regards

Alessandro

Comment: Please edit the title of your question. It's a kind of confusing. Myself can't understand the exact issue. Would also be helpful if you edit the question as it's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` at the front of the import isn't natively supported by node-sass. There maybe a plug-in you're expecting to be loaded if you copied that snippet from somewhere else.